# Block specific URI with Query String in Varnish

Tags: varnish, access-control-list

Can someone help to block an URL which has querystrings as part of it in Varnish ?

For eg: /abcd.php?

Blocking /abcd.php works good yet with ? I'm able to access the page

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can make a rewrite rule and return an HTTP error code something like this:

```
if (req.url ~ "/abcd.php$") {
  error 404 "Not found" 
}
```

If you have some parameters you have to remove the `$` at the end of the string.